# How to deploy code changes done in azure app service directly

Tags: .net, azure, botframework

I have my QnA bot service created in azure. I made small code change in the template, but it is not reflecting. how can i deploy it or verify it is already deployed or not?

Comment: For clarification, is your knowledgebase not updating at [QnAMaker.ai](www.qnamaker.ai), or is your bot not updating on Azure? Can you paste your template code?

Comment: Are you still having trouble?